# Getting text entered in Lua with IUP

Tags: lua, iup

I have following simple Lua program which has a label, a text field for entry and a button:

```
require( "iuplua" )

etext = iup.text{}
btn = iup.button {title = "Click"}
dlg = iup.dialog {
    iup.hbox {
        iup.label{title="Enter some text:"},
        etext,
        btn  }}

function btn:action()
    print "How can I print text entered in etext?"
    end

dlg:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

I am not able to find out how to get value entered in text when button is clicked. I have tried printing etext.value and etext:value but they do not work. How can this be solved?

Comment: `print( etext.value )` works for me.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Can you post some link on the web where this and similar information is available. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=lua+ipu+tutorial does not give much.